# Checksum failed 'download/jpegsrc.v8b.tar.gz while installing SDL. How to resolve?

Tags: perl, sdl

I am trying to install `SDL` but error with checksum occur:

```
Building Alien-SDL-1.446
Build option used:
    Source code build
    z(v1.2.5) jpeg(v8b) tiff(v3.9.1) png(v1.4.1) freetype(v2.3.12) SDL(v1.2.15) SDL_image(v1.2.11) ogg(v1.3.0) vorbis(v1.3.3) SDL_mixer(v1.2.12) SDL_ttf(v2.0.11) SDL_gfx(v2.0.25) 
Building Alien-SDL
Fetching 'http://froggs.de/libz/zlib-1.2.5.tar.gz'...
Checking checksum for 'download/zlib-1.2.5.tar.gz'...
Fetching 'http://www.ijg.org/files/jpegsrc.v8b.tar.gz'...
###WARN## checksum for file download/jpegsrc.v8b.tar.gz is 033998fb47d66e1a5e16a51243424be7a172296b but we expect 15dc1939ea1a5b9d09baea11cceb13ca59e4f9df
###ERROR### Checksum failed 'download/jpegsrc.v8b.tar.gz' at inc/My/Builder.pm line 161.
Checking checksum for 'download/jpegsrc.v8b.tar.gz'...
-> FAIL Installing Alien::SDL failed. See /home/kes/.cpanm/work/1634308125.20978/build.log for details. Retry with --force to force install it.
Searching Tie::Simple on mirror index /home/kes/work/projects/SDL/test/local/cache/modules/02packages.details.txt ...
--> Working on Tie::Simple
Fetching http://cpan.metacpan.org/authors/id/H/HA/HANENKAMP/Tie-Simple-1.04.tar.gz
-> OK
```

How to install `SDL`?

Comment: Is this on Linux?

Comment: The SHA sum is taken from [here](https://metacpan.org/release/FROGGS/Alien-SDL-1.446/source/inc/My/Utility.pm#L123). I get `033998fb47d66e1a5e16a51243424be7a172296b` for the SHA of the file just like you do. (I used `wget` and `shasum`.) Presumably the remote file got updated? Alien-SDL has a [patch](https://metacpan.org/release/FROGGS/Alien-SDL-1.446/source/patches/jpeg-8a_cygwin.patch) that it applies to this download. The change in upstream means the patching might fail. But you could try.

Comment: Then again, the web site [says](https://www.ijg.org/files/) the file was last changed on Sun May 16 10:14 2010. Either way, probably a good idea to loop in the author.

Comment: @HåkonHægland: Yes, Linux Mint 19.3 Cinnamon

Comment: @ikegami: I found that other people also blame archive updating: https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index/issues/4151#issuecomment-767519417

Answer (score 0):

_build/config_data has the wrong first source set for jpeg v8b. The second source passes the sha1sum, but the first doesn't. If the correct archive is downloaded, the  system then hangs up when configuring SDL. SDL_image and SDL_mixer can be manually configured, but SDL_ttf cannot be configured successfully. One should not rely on cpan's sources here. Install all the binary SDL1.2 libraries in a binary distro, also install packages e.g. perl-Alien, libalien-sdl-perl libalien-sdl-dev-perl to have alien installed, and then when it runs the Build.PL for SDL, choose the option to use your own /usr/ libraries (you will see 3 options if it works, choose [1] instead of [2]). Cpan will then succeed with install SDL.

There should be extra instructions with this, that you need to use binary libraries here. Because the script install is super outdated as far as I can tell, if you are running linux that is.